# How to get names of the icons on desktop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

guys.
I want to obtain names of icons on desktop in c++. And I know how to get their handle:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow("Progman","Program Manager");
  HWND  hwndSHELLDLL_DefView = ::FindWindowEx( hwnd, NULL, "SHELLDLL_DefView", NULL ); 
  HWND  hwndSysListView32 = ::FindWindowEx( hwndSHELLDLL_DefView, NULL, "SysListView32", "FolderView" );
```

What's next?

Comment: Well, the icons are just folders, shortcuts or regular files...

Comment: you could just use the file system

Comment: In addition to folders, and files, the desktop also contains namespace extensions.  For example, the "Recycle Bin" icon is a namespace extension that maps views of the user's recycle bin.  The answer I posted below will return objects of this type as well.

Comment: @Bukes Yes indeed this is better than just file system objects.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to get the location of the desktop folder using [SHGetFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762180%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)..  Next, you enumerate the contents of this folder using [IShellFolder::EnumObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775075%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

From here, the sky is the limit.  Tons of information on interacting with the windows shell [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773177%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Have fun!

Update:

A quick [google search](http://netez.com/2xExplorer/shellFAQ/bas_xplore2.html) turns up this sample which seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: It sounds cool. But would you pls give me a sample??? I find out some ppl use ReadProcessMemory to gain that information. Is it correct?

Comment: The IShellFolder COM stuff is all in process, you only need ReadProcessMemory if you are reading from a remote process and in this context it would indicate some kind of ugly and hacky interaction with explorer.exe (The specific layout of the desktop and it's child windows are undocumented and has changed over the years and even on the same system depending on settings (active desktop etc))

Comment: ReadProcessMemory() is *not* the correct approach to this.  I've added a link to my original answer that contains some sample code that appears to do what you want.